# How to create HTML table with complex layout?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I create this table with HTML?

[image: table layout drawing]

I tried it but not sure how to do it correctly.

My code:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes.

The table has 3 columns (cells) and 3 rows:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <!-- <td> from prev <tr> here with colspan="2" and rowspan="2" -->
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Make sure that every row (`<tr>`) has always the same count of cells/columns (`<td>`).
An `<td>` with `colspan="2"` counts as `2`.

- So the first `<tr>` has 3 cells (1+1+1).
- The second has also 3 (2+1) ...
- ... and the last has one `<td>` from the previous `<tr>` which has `colspan="2"` and `rowspan="2"` and the last `<td>` element, so 3 cells (2+1)

Answer (score 4):

You should try this – the table contains 3 rows and 3 columns.

- The first row needs three cells, so put three `<td>`s in the first `<tr>`.
- The second row needs two cells, first a `<td>` with `rowspan="2"` and `colspan="2"`, second a `<td>` with no spans.
- The third row needs only one `<td>`, without any spans.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="150">
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2"  colspan="2"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Md Azad</title>
     
</head>
<body>
  <table border="black">
    <caption>Table</caption>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" height="50" width="50"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" height="50" width="50"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" height="200" width="200"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" height="200" width="200"></td>
      <td colspan="2" height="50" width="50"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" height="50" width="50"></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).